# isolatedModules error on Jest test with Create React App and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

I've started a Create React App project with --typescript. When I write a test Im getting a compiler error:

```
// something-test.tsx
test('something', ()=>{
  expect(1).toBe(1)
})
```

The error is:

> TS1208: All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.

From googling I thought the fix was to create a jest.config.tsx with:

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"]
};
```

However it's made no difference.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You do not have any `import` statements in your code. This basically means you are not testing anything outside of the test file.

If you test something that is not in the test code (and therefore import something), the test file will become a module and the error will go away

Comment: I was trying to exclude test files from tsconfig, but this makes much more sense, don't make tests that don't test anything, but if you want to make a test file just to test if the tests are working, try importing some random module and it will work.

Comment: Adding a random import makes there to be an unused import in the file.

Comment: In the off case where you don't have an import, you can use `export {}`